# Automatic name convention renaming with Python in Blender?

Tags: python, outliner

I was wondering if it was possible to batch rename objects with python, while still keeping a basic naming convention intact.

Is it possible?[image]

Comment: Explain your problem properly

Comment: If you can describe the naming convention algorithmically you can write Python code to do the renaming.  You may want to look at the old [Simple Renaming Panel] addon for an example of how to write code that does this in a generalized fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by "basic naming convention". There is no such a thing for all I know, but you can rename objects with Python in Blender any way you can possibly imagine.

For example if I wanted to name all selected objects that are in the negative x side "Left" and all objects in the positive x side "Right" I could execute this in the text editor:

```
import bpy 

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects: 
    lx = o.location.x
    o.name = "Left " * (lx<0) + "Right " * (lx>0) + o.name
```

[image]

It doesn't need to be this simple - you can program any naming rules and conditions you can imagine with Pyhton. If you need help with this, Blender Stack Exchange is a great place to get it - just ask a more specific question.